# Trying to turn code into toggle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toggle

I am attempting to turn the following code into a toggle where when the user presses the down button, the image is set to the var path but when the user presses the down button again, the image is set to the var path2.

It is important to note that when the user first enters the UI, no image is displayed at all (because Controller2 in the code below, has not yet been initialized)

This is what I had before:

```
public bool OnDown(bool held)
    {
            string path = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari 2600/Joystick.png";

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap.BeginInit();

            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);

            bitmap.EndInit();

            Controller2.Source = bitmap;
            return true;
    }
```

The above code sets Controller 2 image to Atari 2600.png, and thus the image is displayed.

Here is my attempt to turn the code into a toggle:

```
public bool OnDown(bool held)
    {
        var i = 0;

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            string path = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari 2600/Joystick.png";

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap.BeginInit();

            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);

            bitmap.EndInit();

            Controller2.Source = bitmap;

            i++;
        } else
        {
            string path2 = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari 5200/Joystick.png";

            BitmapImage bitmap2 = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap2.BeginInit();

            bitmap2.UriSource = new Uri(path2, UriKind.Absolute);

            bitmap2.EndInit();

            Controller2.Source = bitmap2;

            i++;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the image does not change to Atari 5200.png when the user presses the Down button again. It just stays at Atari 2600.png

The OnDown method originates from the [following API](http://pluginapi.launchbox-app.com/html/61f27087-4b9a-424e-73c0-e482cd2bc0b1.htm) it helps any.

Help to figure out how to get the toggle to work would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counter (`i`) is within the scope of the `OnDown()` method. Every time `OnDown()` is called, `i` is re-initialized with a value of 0, and `0 % 2` always equals 0, thus the `if` block is always triggered. Create a property on the class, I would use a boolean flag, which you toggle, and use that in your `if/else` logic. Here's an [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) on variable scope in .NET

```
private bool Use2600 { get; set; }    

public bool OnDown(bool held)
    {
        if (Use2600)
        {
            string path = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari 2600/Joystick.png";

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap.BeginInit();

            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);

            bitmap.EndInit();

            Controller2.Source = bitmap;
        } else
        {
            string path2 = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari 5200/Joystick.png";

            BitmapImage bitmap2 = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap2.BeginInit();

            bitmap2.UriSource = new Uri(path2, UriKind.Absolute);

            bitmap2.EndInit();

            Controller2.Source = bitmap2;
        }

        Use2600 = !Use2600;

        return true;
    }
```

Since you're new to C#, and it seems coding in general, I'd also offer some suggestions to clean up your code...

```
private bool Use2600 { get; set; }    

// This method can return void, because always returning true is pointless
public void OnDown(bool held)
{
    // The only real logic in this method is which string to use, so the
    // if/else block and duplication of code can be reduced to the following
    // by using a ternary operator, and string interpolation
    string path = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari {(Use2600 ? "2600" : "5200")}/Joystick.png"

    Controller2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

    Use2600 = !Use2600;
}
```